# Shift Invariance in an SVM

Tags: cross-validation, svm

I have a problem where I need by vectors to be invariant to shifting the feature around. The order of the features doesn't matter as long as their relative distances from one in other is preserved (I think, given a priori knowledge about the problem)

For example if my feature vector is
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
then the vector
(5, 1, 2, 3, 4) 
should produce the same classification (binary problem)

Currently I'm using an SVM with an RBF kernel and getting decent results but my suspicion is that for the few examples it is misclassifying is due to the possible shift.

I thought of just producing artificial examples by taking all images with a -1 label (since this is a detection problem and the feature should highlight a defect) and shifting them. I've also seen papers of creating artificial examples by doing something like this to the support vectors.

My question is either (1) is this a sound idea or is there some other approach to try and (2) how can I evaluate this classifier. I've been using 10-fold cross validation but that would possibly put artificial examples created from real examples in both the training set and testing set giving my a far optimistic estimate. I could also just split before hand(80/20) and create examples from the 80% but given that I don't have millions of examples and unbalanced classes I get an estimator with pretty high variance.

Comment: Just to be clear: by "shift" you don't mean the usual sense of "translate" (via adding a constant vector), but instead you mean *permute the components*, right?  If you do mean the latter, is there any problem with sorting all the vectors first? Perhaps a "shift" is limited to a *circular rotation* of the components and not all possible permutations?

Comment: Yes permute is the better word. I need them in the same order but the start point can be different. Think of the vector as a ring, the ring can be rotated but I can't cut the ring up and reorder it.

Comment: Of all the possible rotations of any vector, there will be one that is the first in lexicographical order.  What happens in the classification when you standardize your vectors to that criterion?

Comment: I don't think that will help. Imagine in the example above that if the vector had a feature that was equal to 5 then the label is -1 else its 1. If my training samples had a 5 in the last dimension then the classifier will only learn that but a 5 in any dimension should be a -1 class. There could also be multiple 5s.

Comment: I don't see the difficulties with any of that. The classifier would not ignore any of the components upon standardization.  The standardization merely guarantees that two equivalent vectors will have equivalent representations. Moreover, since the cyclic rotations are linear transformations, they shouldn't impair the ability of an SVM to classify.